# Can I restore my ubuntu14.04 backwards to the time I did the installation?

Tags: restore

Am using ubuntu14.04 and I want to remove all installed programs and files up to the time I did the installation. I don't want to do a fresh installation; I want a restore like the way its done on windows OS.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove only the softwares or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do it as on windows (I guess you're talking about system restore point) unless you cloned the partition (using Clonezilla/partclone for example).

Long answer: in theory, you can parse `/var/log/apt/history.log.*` files, then purge all packages that were installed after initial install, and then downgrade packages (check the earliest upgrade to check what was the original version installed) ... but then some config files might have changed location/name/syntax and ... no, you don't want to do that.